# Can I have pytest-style assertion error messages when executing Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Pytest generates useful assertion messages, whereas the standard Python does not. Is it possible to get pytest-like messages when executing "normal" Python?

### Example

Code:

```
something = ["fizz", "buzz"]
assert "foo" in something
```

Python:

```
$ python3 example.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 2, in <module>
    assert "foo" in something
AssertionError
```

pytest:

```
==================================== ERRORS ====================================
_________________________ ERROR collecting example.py __________________________
example.py:2: in <module>
    assert "foo" in something
E   AssertionError: assert 'foo' in ['fizz', 'buzz']
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=============================== 1 error in 0.07s ===============================
```

Comment: [PyHamcrest](https://github.com/hamcrest/PyHamcrest) might be suitable for you?

Comment: I didn't mean for testing, but when the code is actually running in production. But I think I should use if-statements and raise exceptions instead of adding assertions.

Comment: Indeed - PyHamcrest assertions are not intended only for tests, but also for use in production code.